# Cannot add margin to my h1 after adding border

Tags: html, css, margin

My h1 worked fine until I added a border and made it display inline. Now no matter what I try I can't add margin to the top of the h1. Now the whole top of the border is cut off.

https://dash.generalassemb.ly/Astara303/build-your-own-personal-website

If I remove display: inline the header moves back to a spot that makes more sense, but the border stretches across the entire page instead of wrapping around the text.

```
h1 {
      border: 3px greenyellow solid;
      margin-top: 100px;
      border-width: 8px;
      display: inline;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 90px;
}
```

Comment: did you try setting display to inline-block instead of inline ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `inline-block`

```
h1 {
      border: 3px greenyellow solid;
      margin-top: 100px;
      border-width: 8px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it right away. This is my first site so many thanks for taking the time :)